# Passing a Dictionary object as part of a request on ServiceStack Swagger

Tags: dictionary, servicestack, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm currently working with ServiceStack's Swagger plugin and I'm having trouble populating certain objects in my request, specifically Dictionary objects.

In the image below, I want to pass a Dictionary<string,string> object as JSON for FieldFilter. What is the format for this? I've tried several examples but the FieldFilter object is always being deserialized as null.

[image]
**UPDATE**

I've taken a look at the JSON example provided in this link:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm

which shows that a Dictionary<string,string> JSON representation is as follows:

```
{
   "James": "9001",
   "Jo": "3474",
   "Jess": "11926"
}
```

but the result is still deserialized to null. I think this is more a limitation of ServiceStack and the Swagger plugin. I'll take on the suggestion of using a list of classes instead and provide another update

**UPDATE 2**

I've tried creating a FieldFilter class (which contains two string properties). This is the JSON I'm entering now:

```
{
  "FieldId": "1",
  "Value": "Hello"
},
{
  "FieldId": "2",
  "Value": "Goodbye"
}
```

Trying this (and other slight variations) the field is still being deserialized as null.

As a test, I added the field filter object to my CreateUser request, which has a single body with all the fields required. The JSON for that looks like this:

```
{
  "FieldFilter": [
    {
      "FieldId": "1",
      "Value": "Hello"
    },
    {
      "FieldId": "2",
      "Value": "Goodbye"
    }
  ],
  "FirstName": "",
  "LastName": "",
  "Password": "",
  "Permissions": [
    ""
  ],
  "Roles": [
    ""
  ],
  "Username": ""
}
```

Now in this example where all the fields are in one JSON request, the FieldFilter field is deserialized with the correct values! Is there a reason why it works here? Am I missing something painfully obvious?

Comment: See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm . Shouldn't the dictionary also be generic, like Dictionary<string, string> ? Dictionaries are always trouble in json. You might be able to convert your dictionary to a list of classes instead.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to include it in my question. The Dictionary is of type <string, string>. I'll update my question with more detail to your suggestions